# TypeError when writing a list on a csv file

Tags: python, csv, dataformat, data-formatters

I am trying to create a code to reformat csv files and write it a list of lists on a csv file. The code is not very clean but has worked in the past. But now that I added a new first part to it, where I delete the rows and create betweenfile, it gives me a Type Error. I am unable to realize what I am doing wrong, thanks for your help.

```
import os
import csv  
outputfile = input("")
nodefile = input("")
inputfile =input("")
betweenfile= input("")  
os.mknod(outputfile)
os.mknod(nodefile)
os.mknod(betweenfile)   


with open(inputfile, newline='') as data:
    reader = csv.reader(data, delimiter=',')
    stack=[]    
    try:
        for row in reader:
            del row[0]
            del row[3]
            del row[3]
            del row[3]
            del row[3]
            del row[3]
            del row[4]
            row[1],row[2]=row[2],row[1]
            row[2],row[3]=row[3],row[2]
            stack.append(row)
    except:
        IndexError
    with open(betweenfile, 'w') as outputfile:
        writer= csv.writer(outputfile, delimiter=',')
        for row in stack:
            writer.writerow(row)

with open(betweenfile, newline='') as data:
    reader = csv.reader(data, delimiter=',')
    listee=[]
    for row in reader:
        if row[3]=='1':
            row[0],row[1]=row[1],row[0]
        if row[3]=='3':
            row[0],row[1]=row[1],row[0]
        row.pop(3)
        listee.append(row)
    listee.pop(0)
    for row in listee:
        for i in range(len(row)):
            if row[i]== '0': 
                listee.remove(row)
    for row in listee:
        for i in range(len(row)):
            if row[i]== '0': 
                listee.remove(row)
    print(type(listee))
    with open(outputfile, 'w') as outputfile:
        writer= csv.writer(outputfile, delimiter=',')
        writer.writerow(['from', 'to' , 'weight'])
        for row in listee:
            writer.writerow(row)
```

The error message is:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dataformater3.py", line 54, in <module>
    with open(outputfile, 'w') as outputfile:
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not _io.TextIOWrapper
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is why you should never reuse variables. They have unintended side effects. First you define `outputfile` as

```
 outputfile = input("")
```

Then

```
with open(betweenfile, 'w') as outputfile:
```

`outputfile` is a filehandle now, it's no longer the string that the user type in. And further down in your code.

```
print(type(listee))
with open(outputfile, 'w') as outputfile:
```

You are passing a file handle as the first parameter to open, which obviously doesn't know how to deal with it.

The remedy then is to avoid reusing variables. Why not borrow from `.NET` devs and make the following change

```
 outputfile_s = input("")
 ....
 with open(outputfile_s, 'w') as outputfile_f:
```